# How can I detect where a collision occurs in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm trying to make a pong game and I need to detect where on the paddle the ball hits.  How can I determine where the ball is relative to the paddle when they collide?  Do I have to determine the position of each object and then compare or is there another way to do it, maybe using the getContact method?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "rightRect" || col.gameObject.tag == "leftRect")
    {
       //What do I put here?
    }

}
```

Once I get the relative position, I can do the math to figure out the direction the ball should go, I just need to get that value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)` on the ball, you can easily compare the ball's position (`transform.position`) vs. the paddle's position (`col.transform.position`).  You're probably most interested with their comparative position along the y axis, so that could look like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "rightRect" || col.gameObject.tag == "leftRect")
    {
       float ballYFromPaddle = transform.position.y - col.transform.position.y;

       // do stuff with ballYFromPaddle...
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh thank you.  I didn't realize transform can give you values, I thought it would only allow you do manipulate them.  This will work!